# Create Azure static web hosting from storage account using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to create the static webhosting for the azure storage account using the python SDK.
I am trying to find the examples but not able to find anything.

As per SDK we have to use BlobServiceClient to create static hosting. But i am not able to find any code for this
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/tree/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to create static web hosting for the Azure storage account using the Python SDK.

You can use the code below to create a static website host using the Azure Python SDK.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, StaticWebsite

connection_string = "xxxx"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
static_website = StaticWebsite(enabled=True, index_document="index.html", error_document404_path="error.html")
blob_service_client.set_service_properties(static_website=static_website)

# Now you can see the updated properties
properties = blob_service_client.get_service_properties()
print(properties['static_website'])
```

The above code sets up a static website on an Azure Blob Storage account using the **`StaticWebsite`** class from the **`azure.storage.blob`** module. It then retrieves the updated service properties and prints the static_website property.

**Output:**

```
{'enabled': True, 'index_document': 'index.html', 'error_document404_path': 'error.html', 'default_index_document_path': None}
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

After uploading my content to my **`$web`** container, I can able to view the content using the URL.

**Browser:**
[image]

**Reference:**
[azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python#azure-storage-blob-blobserviceclient-set-service-properties)